# How to check if a button is clicked in another Jframe

Tags: java, swing

So i have **two simple jframes**, one is the **main frame** and the other is visible only when a button is pressed.

[image]

[image]

What I'm trying to do now is to **display which button is being pressed** in the **second jframe**, whether its toy or food in the jlabel in the first jframe.

The button launch selection in the first jframe will link to the second jframe, then the user clicks one of the two button and the button that was clicked will be displayed in the **jlabel** such as **"Toy button was clicked"**

I implemented how the two jframes linked by:

```
class SelectionListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object_Selection object_select = new Object_Selection(); //launch the second jframe
        object_select.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

But I'm having issue on displaying which button was pressed in the second jframe in the jlabel of the first jframe.

Comment: You need to add an `ActionListener` to the _Toy_ and _Food_ buttons. Alternatively, have you considered using `JOptionPane` instead of a second `JFrame`?

Comment: @Abra I plan on populating the second jframe with more elements such as pictures, description and stuff so I ought to to use a jframe instead.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).  2) **See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)** The second 'frame' should probably be a `JOptionPane` which presents the two choices.

Comment: You can have an `ActionListener` class in the fmain `JFrame`, for example : `class ToyListener implements ActionListener` and send a reference of it to the second `JFrame`:  `Object_Selection object_select = new Object_Selection(new ToyListener())`.

Comment: "I ought to to use a jframe instead" - not really. You better use `JDialog`.

Comment: @c0der can i have an example on how to do that?

Comment: To do what ? Post [mcve] to make helping easier.

Comment: I get shivers down my spine every time I see people use snake case to write java code..

Answer (score 2):

Here an one-file mcve (copy paste the entire code into one file `OpenDialogWindow.java`, and run) demonstrating what you want to achieve:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class OpenDialogWindow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main Window");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(400,250);
        frame.add(new Pane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Pane extends JPanel{

    private static int WIDTH = 300, HEIGHT = 100, GAP  = 5;
    private final JLabel label;

    Pane() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(GAP,GAP));

        label = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
        add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        JButton show = new JButton("Show Dialog");
        show.addActionListener(e-> new Diag(new DiagButtonListener()));
        add(show, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    class DiagButtonListener implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setText("Diag button clicked !");
        }
    }
}

class Diag extends JDialog  {

    public  Diag(ActionListener listener) {

        setTitle("Dialog window");
        setSize(300, 150);
        setLocation(450,400);

        JButton btn = new JButton("Click");
        btn.addActionListener(listener);

        add(btn, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JLabel help = new JLabel("Click button and see parent frame updted", JLabel.CENTER);
        add(help, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]